# Calculate time of script execution previously with Matlab

Tags: matlab, time

Good morning,

I have a question about the time execution of a script on Matlab. Is it possible to know previously how long spend the execution of a script  before running it (an estimated time, for example)? I know that with tic and toc command, among others, is it possible to know the time at the end but I don't know if it's possible to know it before.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Are you asking if it's possible to *predict* how long a script will take to execute? I'm certain there will be no command to do so! You might be able to produce some estimates based on previous runs on particular size datasets?

Comment: Yes, this is what I mean! :) Thanks! I couldn't find anything about this on the net!

Comment: Then my suggestion would be: set up a process to automatically run your script many times on various sizes of data. You can then look at your results and see how it scales, and perhaps get a rough formula out which you can then use to produce an estimate based on the size. If it doesn't scale in a smooth fashion though, you may only be able to give the 'average execution time for other runs on data about this size' as an estimate though.

Comment: No, MATLAB cannot do complexity analysis for you. In fact, what you are asking for is even harder than complexity analysis.

Comment: I guess that matlab cannot do it for you, but you can definately perform complexity analysis yourself. There is lots to read on this subject (not that hard to find), but below I have tried to give you some practical advice on how to apply it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not too hard to make an estimate of how long your calculation will take.
You already know how to record calculation times with `tic` and `toc`, so now you can do this:

1. Start with a small scale test (example, `n=1`) and record the calculation time
2. Multiply `n` with a constant `k` (I usually choose 2 or 10 for easy calculations), record the calculation time
3. Keep multiplying with n untill you find a consistent relation: 'If I multiply my input size with k, my calculation time changes like so ...'

Now you can extrapolate your estimated calculation time by:

- calculating how many times you need to multiply input size of the biggest small scale example to get your real data size
- Applying the consistent relation that you found exactly that many times to the calculation time of your biggest small scale example

Of course this combines well with some common sense, like if you do certain things `t` times they will take about `t` times as long. This can easily be used when you have to perform a certain calculation a million times. Just interrupt the loop after a minute or so, if it is still in the first ten calculations you may want to give up!

Comment: Note that for very small calculations, overhead and low complexity terms may actually be dominating. Therefore it will usually not be sufficient to just try `n=[1 2 4]`, typically I try to make the largest small scale example at least 1% of my full scale example.